# Why jQuery has no :readonly selector?

Tags: jquery, readonly

Why jQuery has no *:readonly* selector?

There are *:checked* and *:selected* and *:disabled* selectors for inputs. So, why there is no *:readonly* selector? I mean, as a "coding sugar".

Because all these square brackets are ugly — ".is('[readonly]')". Why no ".is(':readonly')"?

Maybe there is some reason why *:readonly* selector doesn't exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This enhancement was denied in: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/2497

Reason given:

> See above for the solution. Adding new pseudos isn't a good idea
>   because they throw console warnings in Firefox / Safari / Chrome due
>   to the use of querySelectorAll

To see for yourself:

```
document.querySelector(":readonly")
//Error: SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12
```

You could use `:read-only`, though I'm not sure of the support:

http://jsfiddle.net/YGuNG/

Works in chrome but not in firefox.

Comment: The `:read-only` pseudo-class is in [Selectors 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#rw-pseudos), which is still an early-stage draft so its use is strongly not recommended as yet. I'm not too sure if it was ever in Selectors 3. Score one for WebKit on the bleeding edge side of things, though personally I'm not getting excited for it until WebKit fixes its numerous issues with CSS2.1 which has been a REC for more than a year.

Answer (score -1):

`$(':not([readonly]')`... works for me.